# How do I run a query and populate an array before instantiating the pageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am importing data from Parse and trying to put it into a page view controller. The code for the query is correct, but it is not being called. It tries to add the objects inside the array to the pageviewcontroller, but those arrays are empty, they will only get populated after the query. So how do I make sure the query runs and populates the array first?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    testRetrieveInfo()
}

 func retrieveinfo(callback:([String])->Void){

     let query = PFQuery(className: "Animals")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
                if(error == nil){
                    for object in objects!{     
                        if let importname = object["Name"] as? String{
                            self.name = NSArray(object: importname)
                            print(self.name) //Nothing prints, I also breakpoint and it crashes first, crash location is above in viewDidLoad
                        }
                    }

                }else{
                        print(error)
                }
            }
       }
  }

func testRetrieveInfo(){
    self.retrieveInfo { (results:[String]) -> Void in
        //Setup here the PageViewController
        self.pageViewController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageVC") as? UIPageViewController
        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
        var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as? Jwasy
        var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC!)
        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward , animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        print("called")//not printed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be informed when you download the data, you have different options (but the most basic it's set up the PageViewController inside the callback of the query):

0 - You can create a method that set the PageViewController and called inside your callback of the query.

1 - Create your own callback

```
func retrieveInfo(callback:([String])->Void){
    //Inside your query callback you're going to call yours
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Animals")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if(error == nil){
            var results:[String] = []
            for object in objects!{     
                 if let importname = object["Name"] as? String{
                     self.results.append(importname)
                 }
            }
            callback(results)
        }else{
            //Can also create a callback for failure 
            print(error)
        }
   }
}

//Used 
func testRetrieveInfo(){
    self.retrieveInfo { (results:[String]) -> Void in
        //Setup here the PageViewController
    }
}
```

2 - Creating a Delegate

3 - Notification Center

**Note:**
You're recreating the array of names every time inside the loop. Can you take a print screen of the breakpoint?

Comment: I updated my code, but nothing after the `self.retrieveInfo{()}` is being called